# How convert equation environment to dmath environment automatically?

Tags: equations, environments, breqn, transformation

Sometimes I use software to generate Latex which does not support `breqn` package. It can create equation environment.

Is it possible to add some code, in the preamble only, which converts any `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` to `dmath` environment?

The problem is when there is a `\tag{number}` at the end of the equation. Otherwise, using `\renewenvironment` would work.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\renewenvironment{equation}{\begin{dmath*}}{\end{dmath*}}

\begin{document} 

\begin{equation}
-\eta\omega_{y}+\left(  -3y' \xi_{y}-2\xi_{x}+\eta_{y}\right)
\omega-\xi\omega_{x}+\left(  -y' \eta_{y}+\left(  y'\right)
^{2}\xi_{y}+y' \xi_{x}-\eta_{x}\right)  \omega_{y'}+\eta
_{xx}+\eta_{yy}\left(  y' \right)  ^{2}-
\xi_{yy}\left(  y' \right)^{3}-2\xi_{yx}\left(  y'\right)  ^{2}+2\eta_{yx}y'-\xi_{xx} y'=0\tag{1A} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Because of the `\tag{...}` there at the end, it fail to compile. (using lualatex) gives

```
/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))

! Package amsmath Error: \tag not allowed here.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.62 ...\right)  ^{2}+2\eta_{yx}y'-\xi_{xx} y'=0\tag
                                                  {1A}
?
```

If I remove the `\tag{1A}` it works and compiles giving

[image]

Since can't have `\tag{}` in `dmath*`, it has to be translated to

```
\begin{dmath}[number=1A]
.....
\end{dmath}
```

But I do not know how check for `\tag{...}` and generate the correct `dmath`.

So there are two cases:  `equation` with no tag in it, which becomes

```
\begin{dmath*}
.....
\end{dmath*}
```

This case I can do using

```
\renewenvironment{equation}{\begin{dmath*}}{\end{dmath*}}
```

The second case is where there is a `\tag{N}` in the equation, then this should become

```
\begin{dmath}[number=N]
.....
\end{dmath}
```

And it is this second case which is difficult.

Is it possible to handle both cases using some code in preamble? I use lualatex and the code to use can only be added to preamble, not after `\begin{document}`

Any suggestions how to handle both cases?  The main issue is handling `\tag{}`. Nothing else is generated by the software, such as `\label`, It only generates `\tag` or no `\tag` at the end.

The reason I need to do this, is that some equations generated are very long, and I use `breqn` package to break them. But the software I use does not support `dmath` environment. Editing the code by hand to do the changes is not an option for me.

TL 2023

Comment: why have you redefined the (numbered) `equation` env to be the (not numbered) `dmath*`  rather than `dmath` ???

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Because it is my mistake. I actually never use equation environment myself when I write direct Latex, so not familiar with it. But SW generates these. I only use `align` and `dmath`. So I thought an equation without a tag, is like `align*` or like `dmath*`, i.e. no equation number. But when I just tried it, I found `equation` with no `tag`` still generate an automatic equation number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you want `dmath`, not `dmath*`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{equation}{b}
 {
  \nasser_equation:n { #1 }
 }{}

\tl_new:N \l__nasser_equation_body_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \nasser_equation:n
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { \c{tag} } { #1 }
   { \__nasser_equation_tag:n { #1 } }
   { \begin{dmath}#1\end{dmath} }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__nasser_equation_tag:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__nasser_equation_body_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN
   { (.*)\c{tag}\{(.*?)\}(.*) } % search
   { \c{begin}\{dmath\}\[number=\2\]\1\3\c{end}\{dmath\} }
   \l__nasser_equation_body_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__nasser_equation_body_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document} 

No tag here, normal numbering
\begin{equation}
-\eta\omega_{y}+\left(  -3y' \xi_{y}-2\xi_{x}+\eta_{y}\right)
\omega-\xi\omega_{x}+\left(  -y' \eta_{y}+\left(  y'\right)
^{2}\xi_{y}+y' \xi_{x}-\eta_{x}\right)  \omega_{y'}+\eta
_{xx}+\eta_{yy}\left(  y' \right)  ^{2}-
\xi_{yy}\left(  y' \right)^{3}-2\xi_{yx}\left(  y'\right)  ^{2}+2\eta_{yx}y'-\xi_{xx} y'=0
\end{equation}

Tag at the end
\begin{equation}
-\eta\omega_{y}+\left(  -3y' \xi_{y}-2\xi_{x}+\eta_{y}\right)
\omega-\xi\omega_{x}+\left(  -y' \eta_{y}+\left(  y'\right)
^{2}\xi_{y}+y' \xi_{x}-\eta_{x}\right)  \omega_{y'}+\eta
_{xx}+\eta_{yy}\left(  y' \right)  ^{2}-
\xi_{yy}\left(  y' \right)^{3}-2\xi_{yx}\left(  y'\right)  ^{2}+2\eta_{yx}y'-\xi_{xx} y'=0\tag{1A} 
\end{equation}

Tag at the beginning
\begin{equation}\tag{B}
-\eta\omega_{y}+\left(  -3y' \xi_{y}-2\xi_{x}+\eta_{y}\right)
\omega-\xi\omega_{x}+\left(  -y' \eta_{y}+\left(  y'\right)
^{2}\xi_{y}+y' \xi_{x}-\eta_{x}\right)  \omega_{y'}+\eta
_{xx}+\eta_{yy}\left(  y' \right)  ^{2}-
\xi_{yy}\left(  y' \right)^{3}-2\xi_{yx}\left(  y'\right)  ^{2}+2\eta_{yx}y'-\xi_{xx} y'=0
\end{equation}

No \verb|\left| and \verb|\right|
\begin{equation}
-\eta\omega_{y}+(  -3y' \xi_{y}-2\xi_{x}+\eta_{y})
\omega-\xi\omega_{x}+(  -y' \eta_{y}+(  y')
^{2}\xi_{y}+y' \xi_{x}-\eta_{x})  \omega_{y'}+\eta
_{xx}+\eta_{yy}(  y' )  ^{2}-
\xi_{yy}(  y' )^{3}-2\xi_{yx}(  y')  ^{2}+2\eta_{yx}y'-\xi_{xx} y'=0
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The last example is just for showing how the formula should be typeset, without horribly large parentheses.

[image]

As usual, the output of `breqn` is far from being nice.