# What is the status of long equation automatic breaking in context?

Tags: context, breqn

I was reading

[another breqn problem. Extra letters show up in title with cprotect package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375488/another-breqn-problem-extra-letters-show-up-in-title-with-cprotect-package)

And the answer says:

> In an upcoming version ConTeXt MKIV will introduce automatic
> linebreaking for formulas which will probably be much more robust
> because parsing is done on the Lua level and thus avoids confusions
> with catcodes and such.

But the link given does not work. The above 6 years old.

I googled and could not find something relevant.

My question is: does context now have better automatic equation breaking than `breqn` in Latex?
I thought someone here might know.

> but can you please define better?

As I mentioned in comment, I do not have specific examples. But I searched and found one, where a Latex expert in this forum said breqn output can be improved.

Code below from [How convert equation environment to dmath environment automatically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/696710/how-convert-equation-environment-to-dmath-environment-automatically)

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document} 

No tag here, normal numbering
\begin{dmath}
-\eta\omega_{y}+\left(  -3y' \xi_{y}-2\xi_{x}+\eta_{y}\right)
\omega-\xi\omega_{x}+\left(  -y' \eta_{y}+\left(  y'\right)
^{2}\xi_{y}+y' \xi_{x}-\eta_{x}\right)  \omega_{y'}+\eta
_{xx}+\eta_{yy}\left(  y' \right)  ^{2}-
\xi_{yy}\left(  y' \right)^{3}-2\xi_{yx}\left(  y'\right)  ^{2}+2\eta_{yx}y'-\xi_{xx} y'=0
\end{dmath}

Tag at the beginning
\begin{dmath}[number=1A]
-\eta\omega_{y}+\left(  -3y' \xi_{y}-2\xi_{x}+\eta_{y}\right)
\omega-\xi\omega_{x}+\left(  -y' \eta_{y}+\left(  y'\right)
^{2}\xi_{y}+y' \xi_{x}-\eta_{x}\right)  \omega_{y'}+\eta
_{xx}+\eta_{yy}\left(  y' \right)  ^{2}-
\xi_{yy}\left(  y' \right)^{3}-2\xi_{yx}\left(  y'\right)  ^{2}+2\eta_{yx}y'-\xi_{xx} y'=0
\end{dmath}

No \verb|\left| and \verb|\right|
\begin{dmath}
-\eta\omega_{y}+(  -3y' \xi_{y}-2\xi_{x}+\eta_{y})
\omega-\xi\omega_{x}+(  -y' \eta_{y}+(  y')
^{2}\xi_{y}+y' \xi_{x}-\eta_{x})  \omega_{y'}+\eta
_{xx}+\eta_{yy}(  y' )  ^{2}-
\xi_{yy}(  y' )^{3}-2\xi_{yx}(  y')  ^{2}+2\eta_{yx}y'-\xi_{xx} y'=0
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess the answer is yes, but can you please define better? What do you need? I'm teaching now but I can shoe some examples later...

Comment: @mickep I do not really have specific examples at hand. But two issues here: one is that breqn package causes lots of problem with other packages and settings when used in lualatex due to conflicts. Second issue is quality of its own output. I am not expert on the second one. But I will post an example now will a latex expert thinks its output is not ideal. This can be used to compare with what context produces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The automatic setting of formulas will never be completely fine. Let me show your example, done in a few ways below. A few comments:

- All formulas are by default breaking over lines (they are essentially paragraphs).
- The line breaking is controlled by penalties (see how we change the default for binary, something that is on the todo to do by default)
- Delimiters automatically break over lines (first formula).
- Multiline formulas are numbered "bottom right" or "top left", not by a number inbetween formula lines.

I think you need to ask something more specific to get a better reply.

```
\setuppapersize[A5]
\setuplayout[tight]

\showframe

\starttext

\startbuffer[formula]
  - \eta \omega_{y} 
  + \left(-3y' \xi_{y}
      - 2\xi_{x}
      + \eta_{y}
    \right) \omega
  - \xi\omega_{x}
  + \left[
      - y' \eta_{y}
      + \left(y'\right)^{2}\xi_{y} 
      + y' \xi_{x}
      - \eta_{x}
    \right] \omega_{y'}
  + \eta_{xx} 
  + \eta_{yy}\left(y' \right)^{2}
  - \xi_{yy} \left(y' \right)^{3} 
  - 2\xi_{yx}\left(y' \right)^{2} 
  + 2\eta_{yx}y' 
  - \xi_{xx} y'
  = 0
\stopbuffer

Just setting the formula.

\startformula
  \getbuffer[formula]
\stopformula

Modifying the penalties.

\startbuffer
\setmathdisplayprepenalty  \mathbinarycode 0
\setmathdisplaypostpenalty \mathbinarycode 1000
\stopbuffer

\typebuffer
\getbuffer

\startformula
  \getbuffer[formula]
\stopformula

Adding a formula number.

\startplaceformula
  [reference=eq:foo1]
  \startformula
    \getbuffer[formula]
  \stopformula
\stopplaceformula

Using a subformula number.

\startsubformulas
  \startplaceformula
    [reference=eq:foo2]
    \startformula
      \getbuffer[formula]
    \stopformula
  \stopplaceformula

Decreasing the \typ{numberdistance} to make the label fit.

  \startplaceformula
    [reference=eq:foo3]
    \startformula
      [numberdistance=1em]
      \getbuffer[formula]
    \stopformula
  \stopplaceformula
\stopsubformulas

No stretching of fences (\typ{\F0}).

\startplaceformula
  \startformula
    \F0
    \getbuffer[formula]
  \stopformula
\stopplaceformula

\stoptext
```

[image: resulting formulas]

Comment: Thanks. But why did you change parentheses change from `()` to `[]` ? is it just for display  purposes only? All output looks nice and consistent.

Comment: I forgot to say, I just did that to the only one that was growing, for no obvious reason. Use ( and ).